# Как убрать наезд одного DIV на другой?

Tags: css, html

Имеется слайдер и когда я пишу текст после слайдера,слайдер наезжает на текст и текст исчезает.

Текст на который наезжает слайдер: "ТУТ ТЕКСТ, КОТОРЫЙ НЕВИДЕН ИЗ-ЗА НАЕЗДА ТАБОВ"

```css
.me-tabs {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}

.m-tabb {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #757575;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.m-tabb:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px #00CCEE;
}

.me-tabs .tab {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
}

.me-tabs .tab:nth-of-type(1) .content {
  z-index: 1;
}

.tab:target a {
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px #00CCEE;
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.tab:target .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="me-tabs">

  <div class="tab" id="tab1">
    <a class="m-tabb" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
    <div class="content">
      Content of Tab1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab" id="tab2">
    <a class="m-tabb" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
    <div class="content">
      Content of Tab2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab" id="tab3">
    <a class="m-tabb" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
    <div class="content">
      Content of Tab3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab" id="tab4">
    <a class="m-tabb" href="#tab4">Tab 4</a>
    <div class="content">
      Content of Tab4
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<br><br> --------------------------------- ТУТ ТЕКСТ, КОТОРЫЙ НЕВИДЕН ИЗ-ЗА НАЕЗДА ТАБОВ
<BR> ТУТ ТЕКСТ, КОТОРЫЙ НЕВИДЕН ИЗ-ЗА НАЕЗДА ТАБОВ
<BR> ТУТ ТЕКСТ, КОТОРЫЙ НЕВИДЕН ИЗ-ЗА НАЕЗДА ТАБОВ
<BR> ТУТ ТЕКСТ, КОТОРЫЙ НЕВИДЕН ИЗ-ЗА НАЕЗДА ТАБОВ ТУТ ТЕКСТ, КОТОРЫЙ НЕВИДЕН ИЗ-ЗА НАЕЗДА ТАБОВ
```

Comment: 10 раз перечитал, ничего не понял...

Comment: задай position relative к классу контент и будет тебе счастья

Comment: Уже добавлял. После этого Весь слайдер ломается.

Comment: если задаете position absolute то div само по себе вылазит вперед между остальными и у вас версткаа плохо оформлено надо другой скрытый текст завернут в div и задать position relative

Comment: Помогите  пожалуйста примером.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем контент позиционирован абсолютно? Из за этого он выбивается из потока. Задайте `min-height` для `me-tabs` или измените верстку. Вынесите табы(кнопки) и контент в разные блоки.